# Is there a chance my javascript can try to execute before other required scripts are downloaded?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have the following in my ASP.MVC HTML:

```
@if (WebRole1.Helpers.Environment.Azure.InCloud)
{
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
}
else
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Angular");
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/AngularUtils")
```

Can someone tell me if I do it this way is there a chance that when I am running on the cloud the scripts in my AngularUtils bundle will start to execute before all of the angular.min.js has been received from Google?

Is what I am doing a bad practice ?

Comment: It's not possible because the interpreter reads the HTML file synchronously, so it doesn't load the next script until the current has finished loading.

Comment: Unless `AngularUtils` is dependent on `angular`, it shouldn't be a problem if `AndularUtils` executes before `angular`. Ideally you'd want to initialize scripts in the order you want to execute them.

Comment: Yes AngularUtils does depend on Angular. But LightStyle is saying files are read synchronously. However when I look at network activity I thought the browsers could get more than one script at once. Now I am confused.

Comment: If the `<script>` tag contains the **defer** or **async** attribute then they are not loaded synchronously. Read MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes